# mail reader using haskell

Tags: haskell

I was trying to create a mail reader application using haskell. I found HaskellNet library for the same. Unfortunately there is no documentation or tests. Anyone knows how to use this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got HaskellNet from, but if you look at the Hackage page for [HaskellNet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet), there's Haddock documentation.

I've never used this library, so I can't speak from experience, but for example the functions defined in [POP3](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/0.2.1/doc/html/HaskellNet-POP3.html) and [SMTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/0.2.1/doc/html/HaskellNet-SMTP.html) seem pretty straightforward if you happen to know those protocols.

I don't think that library is meant as an end-user library with functions like `mail :: Address -> Message -> IO ()`, although [sendMail](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/0.2.1/doc/html/HaskellNet-SMTP.html#v%3AsendMail) comes pretty close.

Although, from looking at the [darcs source code repo](http://darcs.haskell.org/SoC/haskellnet/), it looks like the package hasn't been developed since december 2006.